# Not able to generate local database file.

Tags: asp.net

I am using Visual Studio 2010 in which want to create a local DB file in my project.

When I register using the pre-built login, Visual Studio should create the DB file, but instead it shows a message box saying

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.

When i try to add it manually it shows the same message.

What can be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: Show us your connection string setting, there must be the problem in connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string on your App.Config file if its Correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="Data Source=MyPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IIQR;Integrated Security=True"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>


</configuration>
```

Comment: You didnt get my Question. If the same procedure followed in other system am able to get the Database Created.  The Connection String wil get added by itself once DB file Created in the Project. Please see the Issue again. Thanks a lot for the try:-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this

1. Delete the following directory:

`C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS`

2.. If that didn't work, then go to `Control Panel` -> `Administrative Tools` -> `Services`, right click on `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` and go to `Properties`.  Go to the `Log On` tab and then select `Local System account` as the option.

The first option (deleting `SQLEXPRESS`) did not work for me but the second one did.